# Create a mixed initialized component for existing fields using lombok and spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, lombok

I want to create a spring component that can be partially initialized automatically by spring (all those final fields) and partially initialized manually (the remaining non final fields). So I used lombok and tried a lots of variants but couldn't make it work:

(ex: adding `@AllArgsConstructor(access = PACKAGE)` will not be instantiated by spring because of
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Task.<init>())

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Builder (toBuilder=true)
@Component
public class Task {

  private final Repo1Repository repo1;     //<- should be automatically initialized
  private final Repo2Repository repo2;     //<- should be automatically initialized
  private final Repo3Repository repo3;     //<- should be automatically initialized

  private String tableName;          //<- will be manually initialized with the builder
  private boolean special;           //<- will be manually initialized with the builder
  ...
}
```

Intended usage will be something like:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationClass {
  private final Task task; //<- automatically injected

  @Bean
  public void createBean (){
    return task.toBuilder ().tableName("TABLE").special(true).build();
  }
 
  @Bean
  public void createBean2 (){
    return task.toBuilder().tableName("TABLE2").special(true).build();
  }
  ...
}
```

Using lombok 1.18.24 & spring 5.3.20 (from spring boot 2.6.8)

Answer (score 2):

Although this may be possible somehow, I suggest a different approach.

Right now you are trying to mix two concerns: the modeling of the actual `Task` class, and creating a templating mechanism for populating instances of `Task` with default values. You should separate these concerns by explicitly modeling them:

```java
@Builder
public class Task {
  private final Repo1Repository repo1;
  private final Repo2Repository repo2;
  private final Repo3Repository repo3;
  private final String tableName;
  private final boolean special;
}

@AllArgsConstructor
@Component
public class TaskTemplate {
  private final Repo1Repository repo1;
  private final Repo2Repository repo2;
  private final Repo3Repository repo3;

  public Task.TaskBuilder builder() {
    return Task.builder().repo1(repo1).repo2(repo2).repo3(repo3);
  }
}
```

Comment: this is somehow what I did in the end, but I was not happy with duplicating all those dependencies